# Matplotlib change graph colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphics, scatter

I would like to change colors in the next graph. I need to have yellow as green color, green as red and violet as blue.

[image]

I have the next code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

scatter = ax.scatter( kmeans['Revenue'], kmeans['Frequency'],c=kmeans['Cluster'], s=15)
                
ax.set_xlabel('Recency')
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')
plt.colorbar(scatter)
```

How could I change the colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would read documentation for [scatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) then you would see option `cmap` for `colormap`.

If you use Google `matplotlib scatter colormap` then you find [Choosing Colormaps in Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html)

It shows predefined colormaps and it seems you need `brg`.

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

random = np.random.sample((100,3))
kmeans = pd.DataFrame(random, columns=['Revenue', 'Frequency', 'Cluster'])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

scatter = ax.scatter( kmeans['Revenue'], kmeans['Frequency'], c=kmeans['Cluster'], s=15, cmap='brg')
                
ax.set_xlabel('Recency')
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')
plt.colorbar(scatter)

plt.show()
```

[image]